# Authentication with email not username

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I followed the basic [Authentication tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#simple-authentication-and-authorization-application) of CakePHP. If I add a user, I can't login with him. The views with the inputs should be alright. 
**Background**: *Users HASANDBELONGSTOMANY Podcasts* with a join table.

---

**Controller/Userscontroller.php**

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) { //saveAssociatied() is described below
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

    }
    $podcasts = $this->User->Podcast->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('podcasts'));
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
    }
}
```

**Model/User.php**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Podcast' => array(
        'className' => 'Podcast',
        'joinTable' => 'podcasts_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'podcast_id',
        'unique' => false,
    )
);

//password encryption
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

**AppModel.php** ([according to this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ccadere/2013/04/19/save_habtm_data_in_a_single_simple_format))

```
class AppModel extends Model {
public function saveAssociated($data = null, $options = array()) {
    foreach ($data as $alias => $modelData) {
        if (!empty($this->hasAndBelongsToMany[$alias])) {
            $habtm = array();
            $Model = ClassRegistry::init($this->hasAndBelongsToMany[$alias]['className']);
            foreach ($modelData as $modelDatum) {
                if (empty($modelDatum['id'])) {
                    $Model->create();
                }
                $Model->save($modelDatum);
                $habtm[] = empty($modelDatum['id']) ? $Model->getInsertID() : $modelDatum['id'];                    
            }
            $data[$alias] = array($alias => $habtm);
        }
    }
    return parent::saveAssociated($data, $options);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what do you want actually

Comment: I'd like to login, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I'd like to authenticate by email, which I have to declare according to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028210/1344855)

So my AppController.php looks like this:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                )
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'xxx', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
        )
    );
```